# How to wrap text and alignment after changing the height?

Tags: css, input, text, height, word-wrap

I have a textbox on a form for people to report errors. I need it to big enough to type in a short paragraph. I made the height 200px, but when I type in it the text is in the center of the textbox instead of the top left corner, and it doesn't wrap when I get to the edge.

[image]

How do I align it and make it wrap?

Comment: the textarea element would be more applicable in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Use a `textarea` element with the desired `height:200px;` styling. The user can also resize it to make it bigger at will.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Answer (score 0):

Try using textarea instead.

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5" style="height:200px"></textarea>
```